# SQL server database log full for application databases

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

We have an issue that our application database gets log full because we have a schedule job to write to a flat table for reporting purpose every hour in the application database. I wonder if we should create another reporting database, and write the data into the flat tables in reporting database, will it take care of the log full issue since we are now writing to a different database?

Comment: Flat table or flat file? If table, then yes the t-log is involved. Are you in FULL or SIMPLE recovery model? Backing the t-log up?

Comment: Please take a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space to see if helps you understand what might cause the transaction log to become full.

Comment: It's a flat table. Basically, we have a bulk insert statement run every hour to insert the records to a flat table so the report can run quickly.